# Docker-compose with image hosted in git in custom directory

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose YAML configuration is made by

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: https://my-git-address.git#:dockers/nginx-dev
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      dev-net:
        aliases:
          - app.dev.local
          - dev.local
    extra_hosts:
      - "foo.dev.local:127.0.0.1"
```

but composing fails with the message:

```
λ docker-compose up
Creating network "application_dev-net" with driver "bridge"
ERROR: no such image: https://my-git-address.git#:dockers/nginx-dev: invalid reference format
```

But it's kind of strange because when I use the same URL address to Git repository for building Docker image all goes well.

```
λ docker build --rm --compress --tag app/docker-nginx-poc https://my-git-address.git#:dockers/nginx-dev
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.57kB
Step 1/11 : FROM phusion/baseimage:0.10.2
---> 4ca439e72536

...

---> 30a38f4f0d38
Successfully built 30a38f4f0d38
Successfully tagged app/docker-nginx-poc:latest
```

Any thought?

Comment: Well it isn't strange... that address isn't an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git URL must not be set as `image` value, but rather as `build` value :

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build: https://my-git-address.git#:dockers/nginx-dev
```